# Acquire Flickr JSON API key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, flickr, api-key

I have created a Flickr JSON-based application. I want a Flickr JSON key. When I try to create one, it redirects me to block.opendns.com, so I can't get a Flickr API key. I just want to test my application to see whether it is working. So can anybody provide me with a Flickr API key?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone administrating your network has blocked the Flickr site for some reason, and they are using [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) to achieve that block. This is why you are being redirected. This isn't a programming problem; you need to talk to your admin, or access Flickr from another network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register for API key in flickr for integrating the same in application. Use the following link for registering. It will surely work.

[Flickr Link](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/keys/apply/)

Comment: no flickr site is not accesible. so flickr key is available for me